# How to use diagxy on sharelatex or overleaf?

Tags: diagrams

In Miktex, to use diagxy package, there a guide that you copy the code in file "diagxy.tex" then paste it in new file with name "diagxt.sty", and put it in same folder with working tex file, and use

```
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{diagxy}
```

But I use sharelatex or overleaf. How use diagxy in sharelatex or overleaf? Follows is my try in sharelatex. I put file "diagxy.sty" in same folder with working file of my project on sharelatex, and use following code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm} 

\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{diagxy}

\begin{document}

$$\bfig
\square[A‘B‘C‘D;e‘f‘g‘m]
\efig$$

\end{document}
```

then having error: "LaTeX Error: File 'diagxy.sty' not found".

The code

```
$$\bfig
\square[A‘B‘C‘D;e‘f‘g‘m]
\efig$$
```

is taken from mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/diagrams/diagxy/diaxydoc.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm} 

\usepackage[all]{xy}
\input{diagxy}

\begin{document}

$$\bfig
\square[A`B`C`D;e`f`g`m]
\efig$$

\end{document}
```

This code work on sharelatex. [image: ![enter image description here]

```
Use \input{diagxy}.
This not work [A‘B‘C‘D;e‘f‘g‘m], this work [A`B`C`D;e`f`g`m] use AltGr+7.
```